# How to set the xAxes min and max values of time cartesian chart in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to create a diagram with Chart.js where the x-Axes is the time.

I want the diagram to show a entire day (from 0 a.m. to 24 p.m.).

Since my data doesn't start at 0 a.m. and doesn't end at 24 p.m. I wanted to set a min and max value for the axes. I tried some varietions but nothing really worked.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="chart-container">
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </div>    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="my-chart.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

my-chart.js:

```
// setup block
const data = {
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Sales',
            data: [
                {x: '2021-08-08T13:12:23', y:3},
                {x: '2021-08-08T13:12:45', y:5},
                {x: '2021-08-08T13:12:46', y:6},
                {x: '2021-08-08T13:13:11', y:3},
                {x: '2021-08-08T13:14:23', y:9},
                {x: '2021-08-08T13:16:45', y:1}
            ],
            borderColor: 'rgba(234,124,234,0.4)',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(34,14,24,0.4)'
        }]
};
// config block
const config = {
    type: 'line',
    data,
    options: {
        scales: {
            x: {
                type: 'time',
                time: {
                    unit: 'second'
                }
            },
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true
            },
            xAxes: [{
                type: "time",
                time: {
                    min: 1628373600,
                    max: 1628460000
                }
            }]
        }
    }
};
// render / init block
const myChart = new Chart(
    document.getElementById('myChart'),
    config
);
```

Is there a mistake in my code or why it isn't changing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use v2 and v3 config at the same time, this wont work. You need to remove the array format and only use the objects to define scales.

When placing the min and max props at the root of the x object for the x scale it works fine, although the time between the min and max you are using is only 1,5 minute:

```js
// setup block
const data = {
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Sales',
    data: [{
        x: '2021-08-08T13:12:23',
        y: 3
      },
      {
        x: '2021-08-08T13:12:45',
        y: 5
      },
      {
        x: '2021-08-08T13:12:46',
        y: 6
      },
      {
        x: '2021-08-08T13:13:11',
        y: 3
      },
      {
        x: '2021-08-08T13:14:23',
        y: 9
      },
      {
        x: '2021-08-08T13:16:45',
        y: 1
      }
    ],
    borderColor: 'rgba(234,124,234,0.4)',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(34,14,24,0.4)'
  }]
};
// config block
const config = {
  type: 'line',
  data,
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'second'
        },
        min: '2021-08-08T00:00:00',
        max: '2021-08-08T23:59:59'
      },
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }
  }
};
// render / init block
const myChart = new Chart(
  document.getElementById('myChart'),
  config
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="chart-container">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="my-chart.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: when I run this code it changed the axes but it does not start at 0 a.m. and does not end at 24 p.m. It starts at 9:19:34 p.m. and ends at 9:20:58. Is this because of the time zone?

Comment: no like I said its because of the min and max you provided in your question, you give it 2 timestamps which are 1,5 min from eachother, if you want to get it 1 day appart you need to calculate the correct timestamps, see updated answer with date strings for 1 day appart

Comment: The min and max unix timestamps in the question are exactly one day apart so that is not the problem.