# react-chartjs-2 Fixed date range in x axis

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, mern, react-chartjs

I actually wanted to populate a fixed date range between two different dates in X-Axis and I wanted to show the Scatter points in that range.

Here is the state :

```
  label: 'Scatter Dataset',
  data: {
      datasets: typeof this.props.data === 'object' && this.props.data !== null ? this.props.data.datasets: []
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            display: true,
            type: 'time',
            time: {
                unit: 'hour',
                displayFormats: {
                    hour: 'DD (HH:mm)'
                }
            },
            distribution: 'series'
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            scaleLabel: {
                display:     true,
                labelString: 'value'
            }
        }]
    },
```

React chart js 2

```
<Scatter ref="chart" data={this.state.data} options={this.state.options} style={{padding: 10}} height={80}/>
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set the xAxes min and max values of time cartesian chart in Chart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68702009/how-to-set-the-xaxes-min-and-max-values-of-time-cartesian-chart-in-chart-js)

Comment: I'm able to add the min and max range but it is not taking the min range, example the min date is Feb 2nd, 2021, and the max date is Feb 4 2021 but in the graph, it is taking the min date from 1st of Feb.